# queue in c Some problems in my code or algorithm?

Tags: c, stack, queue

How to make stack in c, program doesn't output all entered strings only the last
what's happening? Don't know what to write but website asks to write something, argues that there isn's any explanations. When I want to print all books with the help of link to their next book, but it's only outputting the last entered thing. Is it overwriting?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct book book;

struct book{
    book *next;
    char name[100];
    int year;
    char author[100];
};

void setter(book *aza, int number){
    char name[100];
    int year;
    char author[100];

    scanf("%s", name);
    scanf(" %d", &year);
    scanf("%s", author);

    strcpy( aza->name , name );
    aza->year = year;
    strcpy( aza->author, author );

    number--;

    if(number==0){
        return;
    }else{
        setter(&aza->next, number);
    }
}

printBooks(book *aza){
    if(aza){
         printf("%s\n", &aza->name);
         printBooks(&aza->next);
    }
}

int main()
{
    book kitap;
    int number;

    scanf("%d", &number);
    setter(&kitap, number);
    printBooks(&kitap);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please give examples of the expected vs actual behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setter(&aza->next, number);
```

This is the source of problem - where does `next` point to? It contains some garbage value pointing nowhere. It is undefined behavior trying to access it. That is what you did exactly.

Allocate memory and pass it to setter - other wise it is trying to access some random memory and trying to set values in it. You can use `malloc` to allocate memory and make this struct instance's `next` point to it.

To help you a bit the changes would be:-

```
    aza->next = malloc(sizeof *(aza->next));
    setter(aza->next, number);
```

And also in`printBooks` because `scanf` expects a `char*` not `char (*)[]` and also the function `printBooks` is supposed to take a `book*`.

```
     printf("%s\n", aza->name);
     printBooks(aza->next);
```

Illustration using some code - [here](https://ideone.com/LqSXdf). Also you need to write the function for freeing all these memories except the first structure instance.